# Is it possible to autoplay audio and play/pause with button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, avaudioplayer

I need to play audio automatically after open the view and have one button to control play/pause event. I heard that it has a `prepareToPlay` to control the audio by button but it cannot play audio automatically.
Here is my code:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:@"track8"
                                     ofType:@"mp3"]];
NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
```

and in the button:

```
-(IBAction)playPauseButtonPress:(id)sender{

if (self.isPlaying) {

    [self.audioPlayer pause];

    self.isPlaying = NO;

}else {
    [self.audioPlayer play];

    self.isPlaying = YES;


}
}
```

Is it possible to autoplay audio and play/pause with button? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                 pathForResource:@"track8"
                                 ofType:@"mp3"]];
NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
```

There is method `play` is available for playing it. You just need to add following line:

```
[audioPlayer play];
```

Please check the [AVAudioPlayer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

play > 
`Calling this method implicitly calls the prepareToPlay method if the audio player is not already prepared to play.`

prepareToPlay > `Calling this method preloads buffers and acquires the audio hardware needed for playback, which minimizes the lag between calling the play method and the start of sound output.Calling the stop method, or allowing a sound to finish playing, undoes this setup.`

There is nothing like you can't pause the audio if you use `play` instead of `prepareToPlay`.

Hope this helps

Comment: yes, it has but if i use 'play' method, the 'prepareToPlay' method is not work

Comment: why you want to use `prepareToPlay`? If you directly use `play` it will be played at start up and even though you can use pause/play.